# Uncaught Error: Component 'settings': Unknown template value: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components

I try to use knockout components. I use requirejs to load the library into my code, but whenever I do this I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Component 'settings': Unknown template value: [object Object]
```

this is the code of component :

```
define(
    [
        "knockout",
        "text!./settings.html",
        "underscore",
        "../../components/models/tabbed-navigation/tabsNavigationConfig",
        "../../components/models/tabbed-navigation/tabitemConfig"
    ],
    function(ko, settingsTemplate, _) {
        var isInitialized = false;
        var tabsNavigationInstance = null;
        function settingsViewModel(params) {
            var self = this;
            self.tabbedNavigation = new ko.observable();
            if(!isInitialized) {
                isInitialized = true;
                tabsNavigationInstance = init(params);
            }
            self.tabbedNavigation(tabsNavigationInstance);
            self.route = new ko.observable();
            if(params.tab) {
                self.route(params.request_);
            }
            return self;
        };

        function init(params) {
            var newTabs = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var key = 'tab' + i;
                newTabs.push(new tabitemConfig(
                    "Settings " + i,
                    "/settings/" + key,
                    key == params.tab,
                    'greeter'));
            }
            tabsNavigationInstance = new tabsNavigationConfig(newTabs, 0);
            return tabsNavigationInstance;
        }

        return {
            viewModel: settingsViewModel,
            template: settingsTemplate
        };
    });
```

this is the code of requriejs config:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "./",
    paths: {
        "bootstrap": "thirdparty/bootstrap/js/bootstrap",
        "jquery": "thirdparty/jquery/jquery-1.11.2",
        "knockout": "thirdparty/knockout/knockout-3.4.2",
        "knockout-projections": "thirdparty/knockout/knockout-projections.min",
        "text": "thirdparty/requirejs/text",
        'director':'thirdparty/director/director-1.2.6',
        'underscore':'thirdparty/underscore/underscore-1.8.3'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
}
```

this is the content of the settings.html:

```
<div>
    <h1>Settings</h1>
</div>

<tabbed-navigation params="tabConfig : tabbedNavigation(), route: route()">

</tabbed-navigation>
```

this is the content of the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Dipping your feet into KnockoutJS Components</title>
        <link href="thirdparty/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">KO Components</a>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="page1" class="container" style="padding-top:50px" data-bind="component: { name: route().page, params: route }"></div>
        <!--<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 5)"></pre>-->
        <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <p> &copy; 2014 - Still Learning</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="app/boot/require.config.js"></script>
        <script data-main="app/boot/startup" src="thirdparty/requirejs/require-2.3.3.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

the components register content of startup.js

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', './router', 'app/app', 'bootstrap', 'knockout-projections'], function($, ko, router) {
    ko.components.register(app.components.greeter.name, {
        require: app.components.greeter.template
    });
    ko.components.register(app.pages.home.name, {
        require: app.pages.home.template
    });
    ko.components.register(app.pages.settings.name, {
        template: {
            require: app.pages.settings.template
        }
    });
    ko.components.register(app.components.tabitem.name, {
        require: app.components.tabitem.template
    });
    ko.components.register(app.components.tabbedNavigation.name, {
        require: app.components.tabbedNavigation.template
    });

    ko.applyBindings({
        route: router.currentRoute
    });
});
```

How can I troubleshoot this? Is there anything obviously wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I trace the knockout source code. when losing the settings page, the template config is incorrect. I check the code of startup.js. the code of

```
ko.components.register(app.pages.settings.name, {
   template: {
            require: app.pages.settings.template
        }
    });
```

should be

```
ko.components.register(app.pages.settings.name, {
        require: app.pages.settings.template
});
```